# Error while trying to "gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.7'"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

Here's my error that I'm getting:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - /Users/andrewpage/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7
```

Comment: did you install rvm using `sudo`? (you shouldn't)

Answer (score 0):

Try `rvmsudo gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.7'`

Answer (score 0):

you need to clean permissions first:

```
rvmsudo rvm fix-permissions user
```

and then:

```
gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.7'
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using `sudo gem install sqlite -v '1.3.7'`